# mongoDB database exposed on /api, how do I hide this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, caddy

I'm using a mongoDB database, Vue, axios, caddy server and nodejs.

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek50iuo5zkE&ab_channel=DesignCourse
which has resulted in my entire database being exposed in JSON on example.com/api. For example, the first line of the page could be:

```json
[{"_id":"6168115af6bfc986c18f821d","name":"test","age":"20","__v":0},
```

It lists the entire database. How do I hide this?

My app.js file, as in the tutorial is:

```js
let express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  database = require('./database'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');


//connect mongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(database.db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Database connected")
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Database couldn't be connected to: " + error);
  }
)

const cryptoEndPoint = require('../backend/routes/crypto.route')
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cors())

//API
app.use('/api', cryptoEndPoint)

//create port
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Connected to port ' + port);
})

//Find 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404));
})

//error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err.message);
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
})
```

.env.development file:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL=http://localhost:4000/api
```

.env.production file:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL=https://example.com/api
```

database.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  db: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URI
}
```

I thought this might be a caddy (server) issue, but I posted on their forum and they said it was a node issue, and "You should be reverse_proxying to your NodeJS app, not to your database." I was under the impression my caddy server was doing this already, my caddy file is:

```
example.com {
        handle /api* {
                reverse_proxy localhost:4000
        }

        handle {
                root * /var/www/html
                try_files {path} /index.html
                file_server
        }
}
```

---

From the tutorial, I also have crypto.route.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cryptoRoute = express.Router();

let CryptoModel = require('../models/Crypto');

cryptoRoute.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  CryptoModel.find((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})

cryptoRoute.route('/add-crypto').post((req, res, next) => {
  CryptoModel.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Crypto.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let cryptoSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
}, {
  collection: 'sentences_nouns'
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Crypto', cryptoSchema);
```

Comment: I didn't quite follow your question. What does it mean it exposes the entire DB? Are you using any sort of authetication?

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing code of your API. I would say that sending `GET` to your `/api` endpoint returns whole database because you coded it in that way.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, I mean that the entire DB is exposed, when I go to example.com/api, it lists out everything, in JSON form. So I can read everything, all the documents. I'm not sure about authentication, it seems like a strange omission if the tutorial didn't include it. What should I look for?

Comment: @qve1t, I've added a couple of extra pieces to the original question, should I change something to these?

Comment: So, what do you want when user try to access the `/api`? What data do you want it to  return or any expected o/p?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, for example, I need one route to return an entire collection, so it can be displayed on an admin page. But I don't want it to return the collection if I just go to example.com/api/example -- whatever the route may be.

Comment: You can create a path specific to get all details from the collections and you need to write a query for this to work.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, yes, but how do I prevent people from just going to that path and getting all the data?

Comment: You need to add authentication for that to work only those users will be allowed to access the APIs who are registered and you can also then introduce authorization on diff APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question:

I didn't understand how to explain it several months ago but it turns out I needed to authenticate users.

I am now using Firebase auth following this simple guide:
https://fireship.io/snippets/express-middleware-auth-token-firebase/

Answer (score 1):

```
cryptoRoute.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  CryptoModel.find((error, data) => {
    ...
```

`GET` on your `/api` route returns your whole DB because you don't using any query in `get` method. The simplest way to avoid it is to add some parameters to the endpont e.g. `/api/:id`, then get that parameter and put in query

```
cryptoRoute.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  const urlId = req.params.id
  CryptoModel.find({ id: urlId }, (error, data) => {
     ...
```

I would recommended to read about [routing in express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and [queries in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: Thank you @qve1t, this is helpful. One of my routes does need to return an entire collection, so it can be displayed on an admin page. I don't want this to be publicly visible. I'm now wondering if I set up my node.js incorrectly... it's sending the GET to example.com/api, should I instead somehow have node send it to localhost:4000/api and then return the result? This would be safer, right? But I'm not sure if / how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to hide some properties of a document?
if so you should use projection in mongoose
and specify the fields you want.

```
cryptoRoute.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  CryptoModel.find((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data.projection({ name: 1 }))
    }
  })
})
```

so in this snippet, we choose just name field

follow this link: "[projection in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-projection)"
[mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)